# Certain running applications cause middle-click in firefox to function differently under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, firefox, mouse

If I have photoshop, vlc player, or even just the Windows task list open, when I middle click in firefox to get it to open in new tab (by depressing both buttons on my Lenovo g550 with alps touchpad), the mouse icon changes to some variety of scroll type feature, middle click doesn't work, and if I persist then the other programs take focus, and some crash.

I assume the scroll like feature must be intended as added functionality in either Windows 7 or the alps touchpad driver, but no settings adjustments seem to be able to remove this, and I could see nothing regarding this in firefox.  I would really like to fix this!